# How to format axis x date ('dd/mm/yyyy')?

Tags: python, pandas, date, matplotlib, plot

I had searched for how to change the format of my axis x from 'Y-m-d' to 'd/m/Y' using `pandas` and `matplotlib`, but I couldn't find anything that works for me.

So, here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
df_w = df['week'] == dt.datetime.strptime('2016-03-13','%Y-%m-%d')
ax = df[df_w].plot(kind='bar',x='week');
_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(_fmt)
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError: DateFormatter found a value of x=0, which is an illegal
date.  This usually occurs because you have not informed the axis that
it is plotting dates, e.g., with ax.xaxis_date()
```

Comment: even if i put ax.xaxis_date () i get this same error.

Comment: You cannot use a matplotlib date formatter on an axis created with pandas. This is quite unfortunate and usually the only solution to use the capabilities of matplotlib.dates formatters is to actually plot the data using any of the matplotlib plotting functions, not the DataFrame.plot wrapper.

Comment: However, since in this case the purpose seems to plot only a single bar, you may simply replace the ticklabel with what you want to read on it.

Comment: Could you show me any example of code using ticklabel?

Comment: If you provide a [mcve], which can be run in the question, I can provide an answer. Else you might search for solutions to other questions on that topic.

Comment: thank u! I solved that with your help

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with help of [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest), using xticklabels

```
df_w = df['week'] == dt.datetime.strptime('2016-03-13','%Y-%m-%d')
ax = df[df_w].plot(kind='bar',x='week');
ax.set_xlabel("Week");
new_label = []
for i in ax.get_xticklabels():
    date = dt.datetime.strptime(i.get_text(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    new_label.append(date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))

ax.set_xticklabels(new_label);
```

[image: output]